# Next JS and AWS Amplify "No current user" at getServerSideProps

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

While trying to make an API call from getServerSideProps, I am getting "No current user" error. This is an AWS Amplify+ NextJs project. The API is a REST API protected with AWS Cognito authentication.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
  const { Auth, API } = withSSRContext({req});
 
  try {
    const apiName = "productApi-dev";
    const path = `/products`;
    products = await API.get(apiName, path); // this works perfectly in useEffect hooks
    
  } catch (e) {

    console.log(e);
  }
  return {
    props: {
      products,
       
    },
  };
}
```

The API call works perfectly from other parts of the code, for example, within useEffect hooks.

I tested the following code from serverSideProps

```js
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
console.log(user)
```

It prints the desired output-  user information. No error.

And here is the aws amplify configuration

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: "us-east-1",
    userPoolId: *****,
    userPoolWebClientId: *****,
    identityPoolId: i*****,
    signupAttributes: "EMAIL",
    secure: true,
  },

  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: "*******",
        endpoint: "https://*******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        region: "us-east-1",
        custom_header: async () => {
          return {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
              .getIdToken()
              .getJwtToken()}`,
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  ssr: true,
});
```

In this article [AWS Amplify Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/ssr-support-for-aws-amplify-javascript-libraries/), under "Making an authenticated API request in getServerSideProps" section, it says that "Using the new withSSRContext utility you can make authenticated API calls to GraphQL and REST back ends from these server-rendered routes.". The example is using GraphQL and while making the request, it mentioned the authMode:

```
  movieData = await API.graphql({
      query: listMovies,
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
    });
```

I have not found anything for Rest API.

I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is `withSSRContext` doesn't work with `custom_header` in your `Amplify.config`. It ends up sending an unresolved Promise to the hook.

To fix this, you should remove the `custom_header` section from your config:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: "XX-XXXX-X",
    userPoolId: "XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234",
    userPoolWebClientId: "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3",
    identityPoolId: "XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab",
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: "apiName",
        endpoint: "https://12a3bcdefg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/",
        region: "XX-XXXX-X"
      },
    ],
  },
  ssr: true,
});
```

Then change `getServerSideProps` like follows:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
  const { Auth, API } = withSSRContext({req});

  const apiName = "productApi-dev";
  const path = `products`;
  const myInit = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
        .getIdToken()
        .getJwtToken()}`,
    },
  };
 
  try {
    const products = await API.get(apiName, path, myInit); 
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
}
```